# How to iterate through a "box" in a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to iterate through a two dimensional array, and then iterate through a "box" around each element in the two dimensional array, in JavaScript. That is through the three elements in the "row above", three elements in the "row" the element exists in, and then the three elements "below" the "row" the element exists in. I'm running into problems on what to do with the literal "edge" cases. In other words, I'm trying to iterate through the x's around the (o):

```
[[x, x, x, o],
 [x, (o), x, o], 
 [x, x, x, o]]
```

and here's what I'm trying to iterate through when the (o) is on the edge:

```
[[(o), x, o, o],
 [x, x, o, o],
 [o, o, o, o]]
```

any ideas on how I could do this in JavaScript?

Here's what I have so far:

```
//iterates through each cell
for(var i = 0; i < height; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < width; j++){
    var counter = 0;
    //iterates through a box around each cell
    for(var k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++){
      for(var l = j - 1; l <= j + 1 ; l++){
          if(cells[k][l].status === "alive"){
            counter++;
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: please add the code you have written so far

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read especially [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show us some code and you will get more help!

Comment: Thanks! Just added some code

Comment: If `k` or `l` is <0 or >the appropriate dimension then don't do the `cells[k][l]` check. Or do you want the edges to wrap around?

Comment: oh, wow, it always seems so obvious in retrospect, thank you. I don't want the edges to wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of edge cases that your code will fail at when k >= height or l >= width or when either of l or k is less than 0. To fix this, in the inner loops that you are using to iterate boxes around an element, you can again add checks for edge cases using `k < height` and `l < width`. Also in the if condition you can check if `l >= 0` and `k >= 0`

```
for(var i = 0; i < height; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < width; j++){
    var counter = 0;
    //iterates through a box around each cell
    for(var k = i - 1; k < height && k <= i + 1; k++){
      for(var l = j - 1; l < width && l <= j + 1 ; l++){
          if(l >= 0 && k >= 0 && cells[k][l].status === "alive"){
            counter++;
          }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to consider "limits" in your iteration: if you are at position 0:0, you can not check position -1:-1 or similar

```
//iterates through each cell
for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    var counter = 0,
      fromX = i === 0 ? 0 : i - 1,
      toX = i === width ? i : i + 1,
      fromY = j === 0 ? 0 : j - 1,
      toY = j === height ? j : j + 1;

    //iterates through a box around each cell
    for (var k = fromX; k <= toX; k++) {
      for (var l = fromY; l <= toY; l++) {
        if (cells[k][l].status === "alive") {
          counter++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```